# Python - Using a For Loop to create a sum with an exception code

Tags: python, loops

I need to create a code that adds all numbers in the string L. However, if the number in exc exists in string L, it does not add the number set as exc. For example,
exc = 4
L = [3, 4, 5]
Then the sum is 8.

Below is what I have so far.

How would I alter the code so that it works?

```
def summedExcept(exc, L):
    """Takes sum of values in string L except for value defined as exc
    """
    
    sum = 0
    if exc in L:
        



    else:
        for exc in L:
            sum += L
        

    return sum
```

Comment: A string does not have *any* numbers in it.

Comment: This is not a question...?

Comment: Just something worth noting- it is not good practice to name your variables after built-in Python variables/functions; sum is already a Python function so you are essentially redefining it.Does not matter in your case as you are not using sum in the function and your new definition gets discarded outside of the function scope, but still a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer works, but just another more concise way to do it:

```
L = [3,4,5]
exc = 4
print(sum([i for i in L if i != exc])) #8
```

Comment: you can also just use a generator instead of calculating the entire list merely as an intermediate value: `sum(i for i in L if i != exc)`

Answer (score 0):

You should put the if inside the for sentence:

```
def summedExcept(exc,L):
    sum=0
    for elem in L:
        if elem!=exc:
            sum += L
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not call a variable `sum` in Python as its a built-in function, also you can perform a one-liner comparison inside the `for` loop to make your code readable and clear:

```
def summedExcept(exc,L):
    s=0
    for i in L:
        s += i if i != exc else 0
    return s
    
print(summedExcept(4,[4, 8, 5, 2, 1]))
```

**Output:**

```
16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def summedExcept(exc, L):
"""Takes sum of values in string L except for value defined as exc
"""

if exc in L:

    sum_ = sum(L)-exc

else:
    sum_ = sum(L)

return sum_
```

This is another solution without added for loops or list comprehensions. Just subtract exc from the sum.

Comment: you don't know how often exc occurs in L